# Sending two lists via socket

Tags: java, swing, sockets

Client have button in GUI, when client presses the button, two ArrayList are send to server. How server can separate them? How to send one list I have found this post, but how can i separate two different ArrayList at server? [Sending an ArrayList<String> from the server side to the client side over TCP using socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895450/sending-an-arrayliststring-from-the-server-side-to-the-client-side-over-tcp-us)

Comment: There are any number of ways. E.G. 1) Encapsulate the two lists into a single object, send the object. 2) Use two sockets, one for each list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` they abstract the protocol so that the objects are automatically 'separated' for you.

You simply need to send the arraylists with; [`.writeObject(Object o);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
myObjectOutputStream.writeObject(myArrayList1);
myObjectOutputStream.writeObject(myArrayList2);
```

And then receive them with; [`readObject();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29)

```
myArrayList1 = (ArrayList<String>)myObjectInputStream.readObject();
myArrayList2 = (ArrayList<String>)myObjectInputStream.readObject();
```

Just ensure you are reading them in the same order that they are sent.

---

As a side not, be sure to call [`.reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) on the `ObjectOutputStream` if you are writing an updated object to the stream, as it has some form of caching to save it resending objects that have already been written to the stream.